# How can I parse, modify, and regenerate the AST of a TypeScript file (like jscodeshift)?

Tags: typescript, yeoman, jscodeshift

My use case: I'm building a [Yeoman generator](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html), that modifies TypeScript files; in ways similar to:

- Add `import` statements
- Import components into an AngularJS module

Yeoman recommends using an AST parser for this task:

> The most reliable way to do so is to parse the file AST (abstract syntax tree) and edit it.

Tools like [jscodeshift](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift) make this fairly straightforward for JavaScript files, but it doesn't appear to support TypeScript. Are there any similar tools to parse and modify the AST of a TypeScript file?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513148/how-to-write-a-typescript-plugin/40552920#40552920

Comment: TSLint builds on the TSC and allows you to write rules and "fixers" to modify to the code, might be useful.

Comment: What you are asking to do is possible with my library: [ts-simple-ast](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-simple-ast)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `ts-simple-ast` fit your needs?

```js
import { Project } from "ts-simple-ast";

const project = new Project();

// ...lots of code here that manipulates, copies, moves, and deletes files...
const sourceFile = project.getSourceFile("Models/Person.ts");
const importDeclaration = sourceFile.addImportDeclaration({
  defaultImport: "MyClass",
  moduleSpecifier: "./file"
});

// when you're all done, call this and it will save everything to the file system
project.save();
```

https://github.com/dsherret/ts-simple-ast

https://dsherret.github.io/ts-simple-ast/

https://dsherret.github.io/ts-simple-ast/setup/ast-viewers

https://dsherret.github.io/ts-simple-ast/manipulation/

Comment: Between things like this and the raw TypeScript Compiler API, I think there are a few options. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTpKZgy0dpo

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `jscodeshift` supports TypeScript (`ts`, and `tsx`) via `--parser` option since v0.6.0 (https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift/releases/tag/v0.6.0).